# Нахождение коэффициентов аппроксимирующего полинома решением нормальной системы уравнений C#

Tags: c#, математика, интерполяция

**Задача:** имеется набор данных х[х1, х2, ..., xn] и y[y1, y2, ..., yn] (если конкретно --
в моей задаче это зависимость потоков от длины волны, т.е. спектр звезды). Также имеется набор других данных х[х1, х2, ..., xn] и r[r1, r2,..., rn].
Необходимо нормировать набор данных *y[y1, y2, ..., yn]* на набор данных *r[r1, r2,..., rn]*.

**Реализация:** для этого найдем коэффициенты интерполирующего полинома и поделим набор y[yn] на него.

Пусть m() - столбец коэффициентов. Его размерность равна степени интерполирующего полинома Q {upd:} плюс 1, т.к. у еще необходим коэффициент для свободного члена, итого Q+1;

G() - матрица Вандермонда размерности n x (Q+1), составленная из набора данных x[xn];

r() - матрица размерности n x n, на главной диагонали которой располагается набор r[rn], все остальные элементы матрицы равны нулю;

y() - столбец данных y[yn].

Введем обозначения: G*r = A, (A)^T - транспонированная матрица

Чтобы найти коэффициенты полинома, необходимо решить нормальную систему уравнений вида

*(A)^T * A * m() = (A)^T * y()*

**Проблема:** матрица (A)^T * A является переопределенной - число столбцов в ней (Q+1, число неизвестных коэффициентов полинома) много меньше числа строк (n). Чтобы решить такую систему, например, методом оптимального исключения, необходимо сделать матрицу квадратной.

**Вопрос:** как привести матрицу к квадратному виду? Можно ли это сделать?
Или же можно решать систему для каждого набора Q+1 уравнений отдельно?

Если эти операции сделать нельзя, то как решить такую систему?

Comment: Что-то не то вы нам рассказали. Чтобы "нормировать на r" достаточно вычислить норму `|r|` и поделить на эту норму. Интерполировать для этого не нужно. У вас для `y` и `r` наборы `x` совпадают? Второй вопрос. Зачем вы интерполируете через метод Вандермонда? Чем вам плохи интерполяционные полиномы Лагранжа или Ньютона? Вы уверены, что вам нужно делить именно на столбец коэффициентов полинома? А если какие-то из них равны нулю? Третий вопрос, метод Вандермонда работает для случая полинома степени (n-1) для n точек. Откуда взялась размерность `Q`? Как вы собрались делить n-мерный y на Q-мерный m?

Comment: @PakUula Благодаря вашим комментариям выяснил, что не до конца понимаю свою задачу, поэтому завтра разберусь и опишу ее точнее :) Но пока что: 1) конечно, достаточно вычислить норму, однако если наборы `х` не будут совпадать, то этого будет недостаточно; 2) моя задача сводится к минимизации функции вида `{P(x) * r(x) - y(x)}^2 -> 0`, где `P(x)` - полином, `r(x)` - набор, на который нужно нормировать наблюдаемый сет данных `y(x)`. Честно, я не представляю, как эту задачу решить без матрицы Вандермонда, которая используется в нормальной системе уравнений. Делить нужно на значение полинома в т. x

Comment: @PakUula [Откуда взялась размерность Q? Как вы собрались делить n-мерный y на Q-мерный m?] -- я не собирался так делать. Q -- максимальная степень полинома. Размерность n относится к количеству точек, в которых полином будет вычисляться. Возможно, я коряво описал задачу, но в конце концов мне нужно будет делить набор `y[yn]` на значение полинома в точках `x{n}`, а коэффициенты полинома ищутся как решение нормальной системы уравнений

Comment: У вас не `-> 0`, а задача минимизации отклонения `min[Sum(P(x)-r(x))^2]`. Это задача аппроксимации, так как в заданных точках найденная функция необязательно равна заданному значению. Зато норма отклонения достигает минимума. Как правило, в качестве нормы берут сумму квадратов отклонений. В C# я не нашел устоявшиесе математические библиотеки, зато нашел вроде как вменяемую статью https://ilnumerics.net/nonlinear-least-squares.html

Comment: @PakUula пока отвечал ниже, вы уже написали здесь :) Конечно, прошу прощения за грубую ошибку, это задача аппроксимации и минимизации отклонения, но все-таки не конструкции `min[Sum(P(x)-r(x))^2]`, а `min[ Summ{i=1,n} {P(x) * r(x) - y(x)}^2]`. Чтобы не минимизровать вот такую функцию, как раз можно решить нормальную систему уравнений и найти коэффициенты, насколько я понимаю.

Между словом, спасибо большое за комментарии и отклик!!!

Comment: я добавил в свой ответ параграф про интерполяцию `r` и как свести задачу минимальных квадратов к линейным уравнениям.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно найти `min[ Summ{i=1,n} {P(x) * r(x) - y(x)}^2]`, то

1. Если `r` и `y` заданы в разных точках, то `r` можно интерполировать кусочно линейными или кубическими сплайнами. Если `r` варьируется в умеренных пределах, то даже линейной приближение вполне подойдёт для практических задач.
2. При аппроксимации полиномом задача наименьших квадратов сводится к системе линейных уравнений вот каким образом.

Полином `P(x)` степени `m` - это линейная форма от `(m+1)` коэффициента. Следовательно, `Summ{i=1,n} {P(x) * r(x) - y(x)}^2` - это квадратичная форма от коэффициентов. В глобальном экстремуме частные производные по коэффициентам `P` должны быть равны нулю, но эти частные прозводные являются линейными формами. То есть приравняв нулю `m+1` частную производную вы получите систему из `m+1` линейного уравнения.

---

Интерполяция по `n` точкам - это полином степени `n-1`, то есть `Q == n-1` и ваши матрицы `G` и `A` - квадратные. Ну а с квадратной матрицей всё понятно, метод Гаусса наше всё :)

Если в вашей задаче предполагается, что `Q < n`, то это не задача интерполяции, а задача аппроксимации, и она решается совсем иначе (например, методом наименьших квадратов).

Из общих соображений, использовать интерполяцию - плохая идея. Во-первых, задача интерполяции, как правило, вычислительно неустойчива. То есть при небольших изменениях входных данных интерполяционный полином может радикально измениться. Во-вторых, при интерполяции полиномами даже сравнительно небольших степеней могут возникать непредсказуемые по размеру осцилляции, многократно превышающие вариацию в исходных данных (пример - [явление Рунге](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не случайно в реальной жизни используют кусочную интерполяцию максимум кубическими сплайнами.